# SQL query to populate a table using unique/distinct data from another table and a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, qt

I am using MS SQL Server 2012 on Windows7 platform and Qt5 to develop an application that uses a database. I'm good at Qt but I don't have SQL skills.
Currently I have a table named `Devices` that looks like this:

```
DeviceSerial  DeviceIPAddr  DeviceSwVersion   
===========================================
1000          192.168.1.1   8.00    
1043          192.168.1.2   8.00    
1045          192.168.1.2   8.01    
1049          192.168.1.3   8.00    
1055          192.168.1.4   8.00    
1058          192.168.1.6   8.00    
1060          192.168.1.5   8.00    
1061          192.168.1.8   8.01    
1066          192.168.1.3   8.00    
1070          192.168.1.10  8.00    
1071          192.168.1.12  8.00     
...
```

There is also another table named `CommandQueue`, (that is empty or it should be before this operation?) and that it should be populated with data, based on the first table field `DeviceIPAddr` and the value of a parameter (integer) from my app, like below:

```
TargetIP       CommandID
========================
192.168.1.1    30 
192.168.1.2    30 
192.168.1.3    30 
192.168.1.4    30 
192.168.1.5    30 
192.168.1.6    30 
192.168.1.8    30 
192.168.1.10   30  
192.168.1.12   30  
...
```

The value of `commandID` is the same at one moment of time for all rows of the `CommandQueue` table. For the sake of the example/sample, I chose 30.

How to create a SQL query to populate the `CommandQueue` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- TRUNCATE is quickest way to make sure its empty. 
-- If you do a DELETE with a million rows, it could 
-- take 5 min to delete. With TRUNCATE it will take 
-- 1-second no matter how many rows. 
TRUNCATE TABLE CommandQueue
GO

INSERT  INTO CommandQueue
        ( TargetIP ,
          CommandID )
SELECT  DISTINCT -- Only unique rows
        DeviceIPAddr ,
        @parameter1
FROM    Devices; 
GO
```

The following will insert into CommandQueue only data from Devices where the DeviceIPAddr + @parameter1 is not already in CommandQueue. The records that are inserted must have DeviceSwVersion = 8.

```
INSERT  INTO CommandQueue
        ( TargetIP ,
          CommandID )
SELECT  DISTINCT -- Only unique rows
        DeviceIPAddr ,
        @parameter1
FROM    Devices a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CommandQueue b ON a.DeviceIPAddr = b.TargetIP
                                          AND b.CommandID = @parameter1
WHERE   b.DeviceIPAddr IS NULL
        AND a.DeviceSwVersion = 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the `TRUNCATE` tip!   One question if you please allow me:  What if I condition the insert only for device having the SW version 8.00 (see my sample in the question above). How should the query be modified/adapted?

Comment: Hmmm... the idea is that the `CommandID` must be updated to the latest value provided by the Qt application, the old value(s) should be replaced... if you know what I mean...

Comment: Updated -- btw, I obviously don't know anything else about your application, but if you need to pull unique DeviceIPAddr/DeviceSwVersion values from `Devices`, You could prob do that by just adding an index.

Comment: I thought `SELECT DISTINCT` does exactly that, i.e. pull unique IPs. How would adding an index help? I ask as I am not very familiar with SQL.

Comment: So you'll need to do that in a few update statements. (1) insert the new IP's, (2) I'm not sure if you need to remove old IP's, but a DELETE would be #2. (3) Finally update to the next CommandId. Technically you could do it all with MERGE but that's ugly.  The 'hard part' for unique inserts is already answered. Do you need help with the others?

Comment: Well, my first approach - a noob approach - was to iterate thru all distinct IPs from `Devices` and for each one test if it's already in `CommandQueue`, If YES, I did an UPDATE of the fields. If NO, I did an INSERT of a new record (new IP) into `CommandQueue` table... Pretty time consuming I guess?... and quite silly...

Comment: I think deleting all rows of the `CommandQueue` table has the benefit of throwing away obsolete records, i.e. records related to devices that are no longer in the real system.

Answer (score 2):

Use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
insert into CommandQueue(TargetIP, CommandID)
select DeviceIPAddr,
@someparameter_value
from Devices;
```

You can as well hard code that value if you want saying

```
insert into CommandQueue(TargetIP, CommandID)
select DeviceIPAddr, 30 //assuming CommandID is INT
from Devices;
```

per your comment, you can then change the query itself like

```
insert into CommandQueue(TargetIP, CommandID)
select d.DeviceIPAddr,
@someparameter_value
from Devices d
left join CommandQueue ck on d.DeviceIPAddr = ck.TargetIP
and ck.CommandID <> @someparameter_value
where ck.TargetIP is null;
```

Comment: I guess I must delete all `CommandQueue` table rows before that, am I right?... just in case there's already something there...

Comment: Well, the idea is to have _unique IPs_ in the `CommandQueue` table, so... If the table is not empty, there's no other way to guarantee that (_unique IPs_) but to delete all rows prior to populate the table... Or am I missing something?

Comment: If your IP column is a key column (either PK or unique key) column then inserting dupes will fail anyways. So you should consider making that a key column instead deleting rows.

Comment: If it fails, then it's not ok, as I need the `CommandID` to be updated to the latest value sent by my application...

Comment: In that case, change the query itself. See edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: You need to do something to get unique values out of `Devices`. As it is now, if you an IP multiple times you'll insert duplicate values into the `CommandQueue`.

Comment: @RobertPaulsen, you certainly don't need a distinct (probably that's what you mean) and that's why the `is null` check in where present.

Comment: He's changed his question around a bit, but he's got duplicate values for 192.168.1.2 -- the `IS NULL` prevents sticking in an IP that is already in `CommandQueue`, but it doesn't prevent pull duplicate IP's from `Devices`.

Comment: @RobertPaulsen, Ah!! haven't seen update. yes then using `distinct` makes sense but I would still suggest making the IP column a key column. see comment history and I have suggested OP same. Let him decide. I am off now.